# How can I create an Window without menu, bar, frame, 3D effect...etc with exact same size of another window?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

Currently I am trying to create WaterMark window which be generated on Window of designated process.

Below Example is the execution of program with notepad.exe designated.

[image]

However if you look close enough, you would find out that WaterMark Window's size isn't actually same as that of original Window.

I am adjusting Window Style to figure out how to get my WaterMark Window's size exactly same as original Window's

If anyone has suggestion, please Help me.

Below is my code which sets my WaterMark Window's Style.

```
void OnCmSetAttribute(void){ ModifyStyleEx( 0, WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT); SetLayeredWindowAttributes(RGB(255,255,255), 204, LWA_ALPHA | LWA_COLORKEY);}
```

Comment: *"if you look close enough"* - I looked closely, but maybe not close enough. Please add both the expected behavior as well as the observed behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the window size with [`GetWindowRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect). You have to know the window handler, though.

To know the window handles here is a small code (you can find the whole thing [here](https://github.com/manutalcual/winredock/blob/master/src/poshandler.cc).)

(Not compiling code.)

```
EnumWindows (&Enum, (LPARAM)&_windows);
```

```
BOOL CALLBACK Enum (HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    WINDOWPLACEMENT place;
    char window_title[200];
    UINT class_length = 0;
    UINT title_length = 0;
    class_length = GetClassNameA(hwnd, buf, buf_size);
    title_length = GetWindowTextA(hwnd, window_title, ARRAYSIZE(window_title));
    GetWindowPlacement(hwnd, &place);
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &lpRect);
```

> In Windows Vista and later, the Window Rect now includes the area occupied by the drop shadow.
> To get the window bounds excluding the drop shadow, use `DwmGetWindowAttribute`, specifying `DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS`.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mention in my question. 
My whole code actually handles Original Window's HWND.
Also, Window sizes are retrieved from GetWindowRect function already.
However, Thank you for writing answer.

Comment: @KigaelLee added info about drop shadow.